# how to query document using multiple fields from MongoDB using java Mongo driver 3.12.0 in eclipse

Tags: java, mongodb

while using `FindIterable<Document> findIT1 = custDetails.find(and(eq("customer.Fname", "PQR"), eq("customer.Lname", "Mnl")));`

i am getting 
error message as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method and(Bson, Bson) is undefined for the type JavaMongoConnection
```

wherever i am searching in Internet i am getting the same answer for using **and** operator, but then why it is saying that it is undeclared?
please can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Once you connect, you have to specify which collection you want to use.  That error message is suggesting that `custDetails` is a `JavaMongoConnection`, not a collection.

The quickstart at
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/#access-a-collection

suggests this to get a collection:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
```

You should then be able to use `find` and `and` with that collection.

Comment: yes prior to the findIterable<Document> i have written the above locs and here i am connecting to MongoDB Atlas `MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://sumitraojha:<password>@cluster0-tkx83.mongodb.net/customer?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
  MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
  System.out.println("The connection to mongoDB is established");
  
  //MongoDB Database connection
  MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("customer");`

Comment: @Joe You don't even answer the question: "FindIterable<Document> findIT1 = custDetails.find(and(eq("customer.Fname", "PQR"), eq("customer.Lname", "Mnl")));". You've just repeated the Mongo standard example@  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/#access-a-collection.

Comment: @NOTiFY Neither that line of code you quoted  nor the extra code in the previous comment show `custDetails` being defined.  What type is it?  If you follow the standard example and instantiate it with `getCollection`, do you get the same error?